# Is it possible to do some sort of validation in spring integration before triggering the spring batch process?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-validator

Spring integration  is polling for files and then calling a spring batch process. My question is that is it possible to do some validation on the received message

Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=C:\Prerna\Sample\hello.xlsx, headers={id=b29e72bb-f8fe-ba96-36ec-497b3890a944, timestamp=1516903490937}]]

I want to check if the  received file  is in correct format and do some database checks, trigger some email  before calling the spring batch process.
    Please let me know if it's possible. If possible , then how to call the validation part in my integrationflows flow, please advice. Should it be done with handle(service activator) ? Please advice, any code snippet will help.

Below is the code:-

```
@Configuration

class FilePollingIntegrationFlow {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFileIntegration(@Value("${inbound.file.poller.fixed.delay}") long period,
                                                  @Value("${inbound.file.poller.max.messages.per.poll}") int maxMessagesPerPoll,
                                                  TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                                                  MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource,
                                                 JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {



        return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource,
                c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)))
                         .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)                   
.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest())
.handle(jobLaunchingGateway())
 .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
                 .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest() {
        FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest = new FileMessageToJobRequest();
        fileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName("input.file.name");
      //  fileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(personJob());
        System.out.println("FilePollingIntegrationFlow::fileMessageToJobRequest::::Job launched successfully!!!");
        return fileMessageToJobRequest;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway() {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
      //  simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
        JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(simpleJobLauncher);
        System.out.println("FilePollingIntegrationFlow::jobLaunchingGateway::::Job launched successfully!!!");
        return jobLaunchingGateway;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a service method to some bean...

```
public File validate(File file) {
    // validate
    return file;
}
```

then add `.handle("validateBean", "validate")` to the flow before the transformer.

You can throw an exception or return `null` if the validation fails.

> `System.out.println("FilePollingIntegrationFlow::fileMessageToJobRequest::::Job launched successfully!!!");`

This is not in the flow; these messages will be emitted once only (during `@Bean` creation).

You need to add some similar services to the flow (e.g. .log) to log from the actual flow.